# About Ham Sandwich Problem

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have been able to solve the Ham Sandwich problem for three objects in $R^3$ which are open connected and disjoint with the help of Borsuk Ulam to bisect their volume using one plane only. My question is that is this theorem still true if the three spaces are not open? It seem that the distances $d_i$ of the distance of the orthogonal plane for each $x$ in the unit sphere becomes ambiguous. But that doesn't prevent it from existing. (For example take a Dumble) . I want to know if this is still true if openness is ommited and if it is I will try to prove it.